# GeoServer Vector Tiles show tile boundary issue in Mapbox GL JS

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, geoserver, vector-tiles

I use GeoServer to provide Vector Tiles (based on the GeoServer Vector Tile Extension) of my biking trails as .pbf.
The data are added as vector source and visualized using Mapbox GL JS.
Additionally, I use the GeoServer perpendicularOffset to offset the lines (as I always have two directions of the biking trail).

A problem occurs when visualizing the data within Mapbox. The lines are cut at the tile edges, although they are visualized correctly using the layer preview on GeoServer.
The further I zoom in the map, the less the clipping of the lines happens and at a very detailed zoom, the lines are drawn correctly.

I already tried to use a large enough buffer and modify the tile size, as these were suggestions when researching the problem. Unfortunately, these settings had no effect.
I have another vector source layer for the base map, there I have no problems.
It seems to me, that offsetting the lines might be a problem.

[image]

Any idea what I can try?

Answer (score 1):

the tile size of Geoserver's tile grid is 256x256 , but mapbox need 512x512, add a custom tile grid, set the tile size to 512x512, generate your vector tile with the custom tile grid should be ok.

Comment: although I set the tile size to 512x512 pixel, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Have you deleted the tile file generated before?

Comment: how can I delete it, do you mean it could be cached otherwise? 
I just set in my request which is sent to GeoServer that the tile size should be 512px and the tiles given back have a size of 512px